# IOS run app based on location

Tags: ios, triggers, gps

Ive been using GPS logger apps to track my position. i would like to automate the start recording by having the phone sense im on the move.

Here is what i invision:

- GPS locating app off (for battery)
- Reception signal changes reception towers indicating movement or a manual trigger button combiation etc
- GPS location app triggered to open
- In app record tracking button pressed
- Reception signal doesnt change for a specified timeout say 10min
- triggers stop recording and closes app

Answer (score 1):

> GPS locating app off (for battery)

You can do that, but if you want. To do that automatically you have to read the acceleration sensor, which needs battery, too.

> Reception signal changes reception towers indicating movement or a
>   manual trigger button combiation etc

You cannot detect cell tower changes in ios. But you cann detect position changes if GPS is enabled, then you can start recording.

> GPS location app triggered to open

This works only when using location region monitoring: when you enter a specific region, ios can start your app. You cannot have your app started for general moving. But you can app can remain in background.

> In app record tracking button pressed

This works and has no difficulties.

> Reception signal doesnt change for a specified timeout say 10min

This works, too, if your position does not change for some time you could stop recording.

> triggers stop recording and closes app

This does not work, you cannot programatically close your app (legally).